# What GROUPBY aggregator can I use to test if grouped values are equal to a constant?

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Situation**: I have table Bob where each row has a bunch of columns, including a Result, SessionID1, SessionID2.

**Goal**: I want to GroupBy SessionID1 and SessionID2 and see if any Results in the group are 0; I expect multiple rows to have the same ID1 and ID2 values. I then want to divide the count of groups with 0 results / the count of all groups.

***Questions***: I think I want something like:
`GROUPBY (`
`Bob,`
`SessionID1,`
`SessionID2,`
`"Has at least 1 success",`
`???)`

But what aggregator can I use for ??? to get a boolean indicating if any result in the group equals 0?

Also, if I want a count of groups with successes, do I just wrap the GROUPBY in a COUNT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this sample table:

[image: bob]

You can try the following DAX to create a new summary table:

```
Summary = GROUPBY(Bob, Bob[SessionID1], Bob[SessionID2],
"Number of rows", COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(), Bob[Result]),
"Number of successes", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), IF(Bob[Result] = 0, 1, 0)))
```

Then you can add a calculated column for the success ratio:

```
Success ratio = Summary[Number of successes] / Summary[Number of rows]
```

Results:

[image: groupby]

---

**EDIT:**

If what you want to calculate is something like `Any success`, then `SUMMARIZE` may be a better option to use than `GROUPBY` due to their function nature.

```
Summary2 = SUMMARIZE(Bob, Bob[SessionID1], Bob[SessionID2], 
"Any success", IF(COUNTROWS(FILTER(Bob, Bob[Result] = 0)) > 0, 1, 0),
"Number of rows", COUNTROWS(Bob))
```

Results:

[image: summarize]

Comment: What is Bob[Result] = 0,1,0?

Comment: From your requirement `see if any Results in the group are 0`, so I will count/sum the row if the result is 0. You can change it depending on how you define "success" accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate if there's any success in the group, rather than the number of successes? Would I make a third column that tests if number of successes is > 0, as in AnySuccess = if Summary[Number of Successes] > 0 then 1 else 0?

Comment: @Craig I've added an alternative solution. `SUMMARIZE` is a better option for this case.

Comment: And of course, what you said is also doable, so you can pick whichever you prefer.

Comment: Do summary tables account for filtering? As in, if I filter some rows in the Bob table in my dashboard, will the summary table rows and calculated columns be updated?

Comment: @Craig Yes it will. You just have to remember to create the relationship between the tables to allow filtering to work.

Comment: As the tables don't share a column, can PowerBi still auto-detect the relationship?

Comment: No Power BI is not that powerful yet. And also, as Power BI don't have composite keys (as I see that you treat `SessionID1` and `SessionID2` as composite key), you'll have to create a new column by combining these two columns and use this new column as unique key for relationships between tables.